# How to represent a geometric line programmatically?

Tags: c++, math, implementations, geometry

I have been trying to design a library to do some simple geometric computations in an Euclidean space regardless of its dimension. While it is easy to represent points, vectors, hyperspheres and hyperplanes in a generic fashion, I am still unable to find a generic way to represent a (infinite) line, even though lines share properties across dimensions.

My best guess is that I could store some of the parameters of its parametric equation since it is easy to extend a parametric equation to a line in a space of any dimension:

```
x = x0 + at
y = y0 + bt
z = z0 + ct
// can be extended to any dimension
```

But even with this equation, I can't find what should be stored and what should not be in order to compare lines. With an ideal solution, two objects of type `Line`:

- would be programmatically equal (with `operator==`),
- would have equal representations in the memory.

What should I store in order to achieve that?

Comment: How about two points on the line?

Comment: You would do it the same way in math... two points on the line or one point and a slope

Comment: The problem is that neither of those are unique descriptions of a given line. Morween asked for a method that would allow implementation of '=='. The slope and intercept uniquely identify a line. Two lines are equal iff their slopes and intercepts are equal. Store two tuples: the coordinates of the intercept (x0, y0, and z0) and the components of the slope (a, b, c).

Comment: @CharlesE.Grant Storing points would allow implementation of `operator==` as you can calculate all the rest of it from those points.  However, it does fail the "equal representations in memory" part.

Comment: I withdrew my answer, as it doesn't meet the requirement for equal representations in memory, but I would suggest reconsidering or questioning that requirement.

Comment: Are you looking for a bound line of finite length? Or an infinite line?

Comment: @Dancrumb An infinite line. If I was looking for a line segment, I would store two points.

Comment: @Morwenn, quite so, but you never know if something that is obvious to you is obvious to another :)

Comment: @Dancrumb Well, that's true :)

Comment: @SteveEvers Actally, the question about "which is the best representation for a line" is also a good on. However, since it's probably highly subjective, I asked a narrower question about a possible implementation :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you're on the right track with your parametric equation.

What you have there is the vector form of the line equation.

```
L = R + tV
```

Where **R** is [x0, y0, z0] and **V** is [a, b, c].

You just need to normalize your equations. You would do that by finding the value of **R** such that |**R**| is at a minimum, which occurs when **R** is perpendicular to **V**, or **R.V** = 0.

Also, since t can be scaled by any value, without changing the line, you should normalize **V** by dividing every coefficient by |**V**|

Comment: Should that be `L = R + tV`?

Comment: Thanks... I was answering this on a bus on my cell phone; surprised that was the only typo :)

Comment: You meant "when R is perpendicular to V", not "to L"

Comment: Well, **V** and **L** are parallel, so both statements are true, but **V** may be a more practical choice for implementation. Conceptually, **L** makes more sense to me.

Comment: @Dancrumb: no, in your equation above L is *a point on the line*, which is never a parallel vector to V (except for R=0).

Comment: Yup. I'm an idiot. Corrected :)

Answer (score 5):

At a minimum, all you need to compare lines for equality is the parametric equation you already have.

Given lines L,M expressed as Dancrumb suggests:

```
L = X + tV
M = Y + tW
```

then `L == M` if V and W are parallel (or equal if they're normalized to unit length and some "positive" direction), and Y=X+tV for some t.

To get memberwise equality, normalizing the vector length & direction is the first step, but you also need some rule to normalize the point. You could, for example, choose the point on your line which is closest to the origin, and use that.

Pseudo code for normalizing your vectors and points:

```
vec normalize_vec(vec v) {
  // 1. force unit length
  v = v/v.length();
  // 2. force positive direction
  for (int i = 0; i < v.dimension(); ++i) {
    if (v[i] < 0) {
      v = v * -1;
      break;
    }
    if (v[i] > 0)
      break;
    // keep going until the first nonzero element
  }
  return v;
}

point closest(point p, line l) {
  return (a-p).dot(l.vec) * l.vec;
}

line normalize_line(line l) {
  point new_pt = closest(point::origin, l);
  vec new_vec = normalize(l.vec);
  return line(new_pt, new_vec);
}
```